# Using HTML Forms with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm new to PHP and learning PHP by myself.Here I want to get the output value of text fields using php code  but it gives me an error .can anyone point out the error .

here is my code
test.php 
.................

```
 <?php

 $nameone=$_POST['nameone'];
 echo $nameone;

 ?>


 <hr/>
 <h1>fgdhgf</h1>
 <form action="test.php" method="POST">
 <input type='text' id='nameone' name='nameone' >
 <input type='text'name='name2'>
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name="roll">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change the (action = "test.php")
to (action = "") to inform the HTML to look inside the same page for php code . You are telling the HTML to look for another test.php page in your directory.

and you have to put @ sign before ($_POST['someone']) to escape the first undefined index error when you load the page .

Sorry for my poor formatting , I am from a smartphone

Comment: being the best answer is appreciated

Comment: I would not use the @ sign, but rather $nameone=isset( $_POST['nameone'] ) ? $_POST['nameone'] : ''; do it this way.

Comment: all he what he wanted to do is escaping errors ... so it does it